# SQL aggregate folder usage

Tags: mysql, hive

I am trying to write a mySQL or hive query which can help me aggregate on which folders contain the most files. Suppose that I have the following folder paths.

```
/var/www/mysite/current/...../......
/var/www/mysite/backup/..../......
/var/www/misc/others/...../......
```

So basically the query should return after aggregation which folders have the most files. For example we should be able to look at how many files there are in /mysite and still be able tell how many came from /mysite/current vs. how many came from /mysite/backup.

Update 1:
Table Schema

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hadoop_fs_images(
  Path STRING,
  Number_of_files DOUBLE
)
```

Comment: SQL operates with tables.  Show us your schema.

Comment: @PM77-1 Please see my Update 1